Accessing ref current property inside render call
While working on a particular task I came up with an idea to create my own usePreviousValue hook, just for fun. I know there are already a bunch of pre-existing solutions like react rooks etc.
Initially I only worked with primitive values and hook behaved properly. However when I introduced reference values suddenly it started to behave differently.
Logic for the hook is very simple, store two refs and try to keep previous to be always one step behind the current value.
Minimal example can be found on this link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/use-previous-value-sandbox-m6d56m
Upon clicking on the button to increase the value second time, previous and current refs get the same value. I am very curious to know how react is handling Ref(a) access inside a render call since I am not using Effects in anyway.
UPDATE
Upon investigation I have discovered that my approach is actually breaking the Rules of React. Given the same input component must render the same output and reading/writing to refs break that rule.
Pitfall section describes it in details.
To solve the issue I have opted out to use state instead and it works like a charm. That approach is perfectly valid and suggested by the docs here
Initially I was thinking that using state will actually cause stale values for a short amount of time but if setState is called conditionally whole JSX for previous call gets discarded so the UI is always up to date.
Here is the updated working example https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/use-previous-value-sandbox-forked-7wr6pc
Thanks to @DustInComp for pointing me to the right direction

https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#differences-between-refs-and-state

Mutable — you can modify and update current’s value outside of the rendering process.
You shouldn’t read (or write) the current value during rendering.

Your code actually works if you remove React.StrictMode. But it looks like this is not how refs are supposed to be used, you may have to add an Effect after all. Or just settle with the built-in useDeferredValue.

Thats very interesting observation. The weird thing is that also for primitives it works correctly no matter if StrictMode is turned off/on.
I will investigate further.
Thank you

@Tosheen I've added some logging to the Sandbox You'll notice multiple renders per increment and interesting assertions such as {"counter":2} does not equal {"counter":2}. React may be doing some copying/object-spreading under the hood.

Yeah that was my initial thought, and thats why I used Object.is just to be sure.
By the spec react is guaranteeing stable references across useState calls

DustInComp did you save your adjustments. For some reason I am not seeing them

Oh, looks like I pasted the wrong link somehow. Here's the updated Sandbox
